# "Не знаю(,) что и делать" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятые, сказуемые

> *Ну а с этими шмотками не знаю(,) что и делать.*

Понятно, что без И естественно поставить запятую. А так уж очень интонационно хочется без неё...

Comment: Хм. А ведь действительно... С частицей "и" логическое ударение перестаёт падать на "знаю".

Comment: Согласен, что хочется. Но в нацкорпусе запятая стоит, кроме текстов с явными пунктуационными ошибками (да-да). Даже когда "не знаю" стоит в начале.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Ну а с этими шмотками не знаю что и делать.***

Запятую не ставим.

Конечно, практически во всех случаях запятая ставится (по крайней мере, в письменных текстах): ***не знАю, что и дЕлать***. Ударением выделяется и глагол, и оборот.

Например: *Может, ты в армии станешь на человека похож. А то совсем **не знаю, что и делать.***  [Сергей Довлатов. (1965)]

**Но у нас особый случай.**

Сравним: *Не знаю,  что и делать с этими шмотками.* А теперь используем инверсию: *С этими шмотками не знаю что и делать.*

Если поставить запятую, то **дополнение будет отделено от управляющего глагола**, а это не есть хорошо. **Именно инверсия переводит предложение в "неразложимую конструкцию".**

Сравнить с примерами из Розенталя (влияние инверсии): Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга. Он уже месяц как вернулся с юга.

Пример из литературы: *Относительно контракта **я не знаю что и делать**.* [В. М. Гаршин. Письма Е.С. Гаршиной (1875)]

В современных текстах тоже встречается такой вариант, когда в начале предложения стоит дополнение, относящееся ко второй части предложения. Что-то вроде такого предложения: *А с Тамарой я не знаю что и делать.* **Запятую здесь никак не получается поставить.**

И у **современных авторитетных классиков** надо найти предложение именно **такой структуры (с дополнением в начале предложения)**, чтобы понять, ставили они запятую или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Очень рад, что нашлось столько аргументов в пользу отсутствия запятой!

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не ставится, если за "что" следует существительное. Если же "что" выступает в роли разделителя сложно-какого-то-там предложения либо если за "что" следует глагол, запятая имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: "Не знаю, что Вася придумает на этот раз". Пожалуйста, вот вам существительное.

Comment: *ушел штудировать справочник, вернусь не скоро =)*

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна. Но с одним НО.
То, что там ударение не туда падает - это вне правил правописания.
А вот если автор рассматривает весь оборот как нечленимый, то у него есть маленький шанс эту акцентуацию подчеркнуть.
Полагаю, этим и объясняется отсутствие запятых у классиков. Хотя напечатанное до 1956-го и само по себе - аргумент слабый. В современных авторитетных текстах запятая проставлена последовательно.

Comment: Спасибо, Бегемотус! Да, я рассматриваю оборот как нечленимый и не хочу ставить запятую. :)